# using scrapy to build a spider

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I am building a simple scraper to get data from a crowdfunding site. I run the scraper then try to output the data to a csv file. Unfortunately, my csv file keeps turning up blank. I have tried numerous suggestions but nothing seems to be working. Here is an example of what I have written:

```
class Crowdfund_Helphopelive(scrapy.Spider):
name = "helphopelive_scraper"   

def start_requests(self):
    #make list of individual campaign sites
    start_urls = ["https://helphopelive.org/campaign/10798/",
                  "https://helphopelive.org/campaign/13083/"]
    for url in start_urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url,callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    #parse individual campaign sites

    #create instance of the item
    item = HelphopeliveItem()

    #get amount raised
    item['amount_raised'] = response.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'teal')]/descendant::text()").extract()[0]
    #get the goal
    item['goal'] = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'profile-lockup__footer')]/p/text()").extract()[0]

    #get the url
    item['url'] = response.xpath("//meta[@property='og:url']/@content").extract()[0]

    yield item
```

Would be grateful for some help so that I can understand what I am missing.

Comment: @d-barnes, I think you're missing a `write.csv()` function call. The scraper is doing the parsing thing but then there is no call to writing the output to the disc.

Comment: @Ashish, it is not enough to do `scrapy crawl <spider name> -o file.csv` ?